# A custom single-lined representation of a piecewise definition

Tags: macros, cases

I would like to have a macro that realizes the following representation of a piecewise definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \exists g \in X \to Y: \forall x \in X:
    \langle x \in A \Rightarrow g(x) = 0;~ x \notin A \Rightarrow g(x) \in B \rangle
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

whose output looks like

[image]

The desired macro can be used with the following syntax:

```
\scases{
    x \in A & g(x) = 0\\
    x \notin A & g(x) \in B
}
```

or one that is analogous to the `cases` environment:

```
\begin{scases}
    x \in A & g(x) = 0\\
    x \notin A & g(x) \in B
\end{scases}
```

whose output will be identical to the part enclosed by the brackets `\langle` and `\rangle`.

[image]

That is, `&` is replaced by the conditional $ \Rightarrow $, and `\\` by `;~`.

Please help me design such a macro.

**Request update**: The macro should allow arbitrarily many `\\`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following macro does what you want:

```
\def\scases #1{\bgroup \def\\{;~}\langle \scasesA #1&\egroup}
\def\scasesA #1&{#1\futurelet\next\scasesB}
\def\scasesB {\ifx\next\egroup \rangle \else \Rightarrow \expandafter\scasesA \fi}

% test:
$$
\scases{
    x \in A & g(x) = 0\\
    x \notin A & g(x) \in B
}
$$
\bye
```

Comment: Yes, it perfectly does :) Thank you. Would you please make an environment version of the macro? In fact, the environment can be trivially made by using `\scases` but I want one that bypasses it.

Comment: By the way, I don't know why `\NewEnviron{scenv}{\scases{\BODY}}` does not work.

Comment: Look at the documentation of environ package. You can use it and `\expandafter\scases\expandafter{\BODY}`. I don't know this exactly because I am not using LaTeX. The pure `\scases{...}` is more native from my point of view. Environments are only LaTeX's complications.

Comment: It works great. Thank you so much for your aid.