# To convert a macro to an environment

Tags: macros, environments

I decided to convert the macro `\scases` defined in the [nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/636356/142888) of my previous question by wipet to improve the legibility of the code. (Whether it is really an improvement is based on my personal preference.)

The original macro:

```
\def\scases #1{\bgroup \def\\{;~}\langle \scasesA #1&\egroup}
\def\scasesA #1&{#1\futurelet\next\scasesB}
\def\scasesB {\ifx\next\egroup \rangle \else \Rightarrow \expandafter\scasesA \fi}
```

whose output for

```
\begin{equation*}
    \scases{
        x \in A & g(x) = 0\\
        x \notin A & g(x) \in B
    }
\end{equation*}
```

is

[image]

There is also an option to reuse `\scases` as follows, but I want to make a standalone version:

```
\NewEnviron{scenv}{\expandafter\scases\expandafter{\BODY}}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{scenv}
        x \in A & g(x) = 0\\
        x \notin A & g(x) \in B
    \end{scenv}
\end{equation*}
```

Here are some of what I've tried in vain:

1.

```
\newenvironment{scenv}{
    \bgroup\def\\{;~}\langle \scasesA
}{
    &\egroup
}
```

[image]
(incomplete)

2.

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{scenv}{\bgroup \def\\{;~}\langle \scasesA{\BODY}&\egroup}
```

[image]
(=> is missing)

I think I don't sufficiently understand how `\def` works.

I prefer using `\newenvironment` to `\NewEnviron`, but either way is good enough.

I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `&` for a non-alignment makes it more complicated than it would oherwise be but..

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{SCASES}
  {\def\\{;~\SCASESA}\langle \SCASESA}
  {\rangle}
\def\SCASESA #1&{#1\Rightarrow}



\begin{equation*}
    \begin{SCASES}
        x \in A & g(x) = 0\\
        x \notin A & g(x) \in B
     \end{SCASES}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this is another valuable solution to my original question. It's simple and elegant :) Thank you very much!

Comment: As a novice, may I ask for a better setup for this purpose?

Comment: @egreg how wide is your paper:-)   seems to work for three to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expl3` that is much more direct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{scases}{b}
  {
    \langle
    \hermis_scases:n { #1 } % absorb the entire contents as #1
    \rangle
  }
  {}

\seq_new:N \l__hermis_scases_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__hermis_scases_out_seq
\tl_new:N \l__hermis_scases_case_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hermis_scases:n
  {
    % split at \\
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__hermis_scases_in_seq { \\ } { #1 }
    % wrap every item in the processing function
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l__hermis_scases_out_seq \l__hermis_scases_in_seq
      {
        \__hermis_scases_case:n { ##1 }
      }
    % use the sequence with ;<space> between items
    \seq_use:Nn \l__hermis_scases_out_seq { ;\mspace{\thickmuskip} }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hermis_scases_case:n
  {
    % save the contents
    \tl_set:Nn \l__hermis_scases_case_tl { #1 }
    % replace & with \Rightarrow
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l__hermis_scases_case_tl { & } { \Rightarrow }
    % deliver the new contents
    \tl_use:N \l__hermis_scases_case_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{scases}
    x \in A & g(x) = 0 \\
    x \notin A & g(x) \in B
  \end{scases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{scases}
    x \in A & g(x) = 1 \\
    x \in B & g(x) = 2 \\
    x \in C & g(x) = 3
  \end{scases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your elaborated answer! But I am curious about the computational efficiency regarding the use of `expl3`. Is it efficient enough to be free of any cause of lag?

Comment: @Hermis14 Twelve pages worth of `scases` typeset in less than 1 second on my machine.

Comment: @Hermis14 compared to the code in my answer it will be technically slower but expl3 code has been optimised over many decades and speed isn't an issue, if you have tens of thousands of such equations you may see something but otherwise tex probably spends longer reading your file off the filesystem than it does executing either version of the code.

Comment: @Hermis14 I tries David's environment and the time is essentially the same. Of course, with some thousands of these environments you might see a slight slowdown.

Comment: @egreg The discussion with David and your verification effort really helped me a lot.